# Need to split MySQL results into 3 per row

Tags: php, mysql, limit, rows

I'm wanting to split the results from a database into 3 results per row. This is the code I have:

```
include("connect.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY title");
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);

if ($num > 0 ) {
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {
        $id = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"id"));
        $title = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"title"));
        $description = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"description"));
        $length = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"length"));
        $link = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"link"));
        $rating = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"rating"));
        $cover = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"icover"));

        $row .= '<tr><td><a href="view.php?id='.$id.'"><img width=130 height=190 src="images/covers/'.$cover.'" /></a></td><td valign="top">'.$title.'<br />'.$rating.'<br />Run Time: '.$length.'</td><td><a href="update.php?id='.$id.'">Update</a></td><td><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></td></tr>';

        ++$i; 
    }
} 
else { 
    $row = '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Nothing found</td></tr>'; 
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a query result and how you'd like it formatted?  It's not too clear from your source just what you're trying to do.

Comment: The modulus operator is your friend.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @JohnConde They're actually officially deprecated now. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/3881905) the updated *Don't use ext mysql* comment

Comment: **Whoa!**  `stripslashes`?  Unless you have Magic Quotes turned on -- and you *shouldn't* -- you have a serious code smell problem.  `stripslashes` and it's evil twin `addslashes` are *never, ever* the right thing to use.  Please listen to what John Conde said and switch over to a modern database interface library.

Answer (score 2):

As someone pointed out, if you want to do something every Nth time, you generally want a check of the form:

```
if ( $i > 0 && $i % $N == 0) {
    // Do your Nth something here
}
```

Where $i is your current iteration number, and of course $N is how often you want to break.  So in this case, $N = 3, and your breaking logic would go in the body of the if statement.

Having said that, it looks like there may be more involved than just that; your code already has quite a bit going on in your table, as you already have multiple columns per row.  Did you really want 3 sets of those multiple columns, or did you mean something else, like row groupings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to define the $row over the if statement , in this case your variable will be local variable inside the while only

```
include("connect.php");

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY title");
 $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
 $row = '';

 if ($num > 0 ) {
    $i=0;


   while ($i < $num) {

   $id = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"id"));
   $title = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"title"));
   $description = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"description"));
   $length = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"length"));
   $link = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"link"));
   $rating = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"rating"));
   $cover = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"icover"));

   $row .= '<tr>
   <td><a href="view.php?id='.$id.'"><img width=130 height=190 src="images/covers/'.$cover.'" /></a></td>
   <td valign="top">'.$title.'<br />'.$rating.'<br />Run Time: '.$length.'</td>
   <td><a href="update.php?id='.$id.'">Update</a></td>
   <td><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>';

  ++$i; }
 } else { $row = '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Nothing found</td></tr>'; }

  mysql_close();

  print($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you with what you are trying to do. Of course you will need to style the table to meet your needs. You can set the number of columns in the code to whatever fits for you.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
            $mysqli->close();
        }

    $values = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY title");
    $cols = 3;
    $i =1;
    echo "<table>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
while($row = $values->fetch_assoc())
    { 
        $id             = $row['id'];
        $title          = $row['title'];
        $description    = $row['description'];
        $length         = $row['length'];
        $link           = $row['link'];
        $rating         = $row['rating'];
        $cover          = $row['icover'];
    if (is_int($i / $cols))
        {
            echo "<td >".PHP_EOL;
            //what ever you want to include goes here
            echo "</td>".PHP_EOL;
            echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
            echo "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
            {
                echo "<td >".PHP_EOL;
                //what ever you want to include goes here
                echo "</td>".PHP_EOL;
            }
            $i++;
    }
        echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL; 
        echo "</table>".PHP_EOL;
```